# What are the relationships between price stability and long term economic growth?

Tags: economic-growth, price-level, long-run

I was wondering what the links are between price stability and economic growth on the long term.

Comment: price stability and growth are inextricably linked by the fact that price stability prevents instances of exaggerated inflation and deflation. What does deflation do to an economy?Too much Inflation?